# Unable to change state when combining multiple reducers

Tags: redux, next.js

I have two reducers:

```
// reducer/reducers/credentialsErrorDisplay.js

export default function credentialsErrorDisplay(state = 'none', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FLAGCREDENTIALSERROR':
      return { action.payload };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

```
// reducer/reducers/emailWarning.js

export default function emailWarning(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'WARNFOREXISTINGEMAIL':
      return { action.payload };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And I am trying to combine them into one like this:

```
reducer/index.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import credentialsErrorDisplay from './reducers';
import emailWarning from './reducers';

const mainReducer = combineReducers({
  credentialsErrorDisplay,
  emailWarning,
});

const makeStore = initialState => createStore(mainReducer, initialState);

export default makeStore;
```

But when run, the actions fail to be called and the state remains unchanged. Am I missing something? All I'm trying to do is break one giant reducer into multiple manageable files to make the code easier to maintain. But nothing seems to be working.

**UPDATE**: Just spotted and fixed a couple of import errors that seems to have an effect. Now, it's throwing the following compile-time error:

```
./reducers/reducers/credentialsErrorDisplay.js
SyntaxError: /home/ubuntu/proost/web/reducers/reducers/credentialsErrorDisplay.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (4:21)

  2 |   switch (action.type) {
  3 |     case 'FLAGCREDENTIALSERROR':
> 4 |       return { action.payload };
    |                      ^
  5 |     default:
  6 |       return state
  7 |   }
```

Comment: do you have installed redux-devtools and the browser extension?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant to pass to `createStore` is mainReducer, not reducer. In my current project, we did it a little differently, importing all our reducers, then simply exporting the `combineReducers` directly:

```js
export default combineReducers({reducer1, reducer2, reducer3});
```

and then in the `index.js` in the project root:

```js
import rootReducer from './js/reducers/RootReducer';
...
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

That gives us all our stores.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo. mainReducer is what am actually passing to createStore. Fixed it in the code.